# Asignar la ruta de un archivo a una variable para luego usarla en FFmpeg

Tags: python, pyqt, video

Estoy intentando hacer un programa en *Python* y *PyQt* para codificación de vídeo y me ha surgido un problema.

No sé cómo conseguir tener una variable con la ruta de un archivo para luego poderlo enviar a *FFmpeg*.

He construido una ventana básica con tres botones, uno para elegir el archivo, otro para elegir ruta del archivo saliente y otro para comenzar la codificación. A este último ahora solo le pido que me imprima la variable que tiene la ruta del archivo para poderla ver y comprobar que esa variable está bien.

Si ejecuto el primer botón, `b1_clicked()`, funciona bien e incluso imprime la ruta del archivo, pero si ejecuto el tercer botón también para imprimir esa variable, da error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/salva/PycharmProjects/prueba1/encoder3.py", line 40, in b3_clicked
>
> print (fileinput)
>
> NameError: name 'fileinput' is not defined

Necesito esa variable para poder enviar a *FFmpeg* el vídeo que quiero codificar (ya veré cómo).

En ese botón 3 actuará *FFmpeg* más adelante cuando sepa como hacerlo.

Así lo llevo por ahora antes de empezar con *FFmpeg*: (voy actualizando)

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import subprocess

fileinput = ''

def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   win = QDialog()
   b1 = QPushButton(win)
   b1.setText("Select file")
   b1.move(50,20)
   b1.clicked.connect(b1_clicked)

   b2 = QPushButton(win)
   b2.setText("Output file")
   b2.move(50,50)
   b2.clicked.connect(b2_clicked)

   b3 = QPushButton(win)
   b3.setText("Encode!")
   b3.move(50,80)
   b3.clicked.connect(b3_clicked)

   win.setGeometry(100,100,200,200)
   win.setWindowTitle("Encoder")
   win.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

def b1_clicked():
   fileinput = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Selecciona archivo a convertir", "/home/salva", "video files (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.mov *.mpg);; All files (*)")
   print (fileinput)


def b2_clicked():
   filesaved = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Archivo de salida", "/home/salva", "video files (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.mov *.mpg);; All files (*)")
   print (filesaved)


def b3_clicked():
   print (fileinput)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque `fileinput` solo la conoce `b1_clicked()`, ya que es local. Esto es, una variable local solo existe en el ámbito de la función (en realidad del espacio o *namespace*) que la crea. Por lo tanto, dicha variable no existe en `b3_clicked()` (el término correcto es *no está en su alcance*).

Tienes dos opciones.

1. Le pasas de alguna manera esa variable a la función `b3_clicked()` o
2. Crea la variable `fileinput` en el espacio global, para que esté al alcance de todas las funciones y métodos:

Ejemplo:

```
# tus imports 

fileinput = ''   # Creas una variable global, vacía

# la función window()

def b1_clicked():
   global fileinput 
   fileinput = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Selecciona archivo a convertir", "/home/salva", "video files (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.mov *.mpg);; All files (*)")
   print (fileinput)  # Usas la variable global

def b3_clicked():
   # Haces algo si `fileinput` está vacía
   print (fileinput)
```

Comment: b3_cliked no me funciona después de hacer lo que me aconsejas. fileinput la he sacado fuera pero al clicar b3 no imprime la ruta. No da error pero no imprime nada. Esto lo hago solo para comprobar que fileinput tiene algo. Más tarde el botón 3 será el que ejecute ffmpeg con esa variable como input del archivo del vídeo

Comment: Bueno @salvaestudio, en realidad no funcionaba desde el principio. Revisa qué es lo que estas haciendo y edita tu pregunta con las modificaciones.

Comment: Primero pulso el botón 1 y selecciono archivo. Luego pulso botón 3 y no me imprime nada. ¿? La idea es comprobar que la variable la puedo usar en otro momento con ffmpeg

Comment: @salvaestudio al oprimir el botón 1, debe imprimir la ruta del archivo seleccionado, ¿eso si pasa?

Comment: Si, eso si. Pero necesito poder tener otro botón para mandar codificar el vídeo.

Comment: Tienes razón, faltaba el atributo `global`.

Comment: Genial! @toledano Gracias. El b3 ya puede imprimir la ruta del archivo.

Comment: @salvaestudio, si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Soy un poco nuevo en esto. ¿cómo marco?

Comment: Al lado izquierdo de la respuesta, justo debajo del número de votos, hay una marca/paloma/check que sirve para indicar que la respuesta te sirvió y es la que aceptas. Ayuda a otras personas que tengan dudas similares a la tuya a elegir respuestas con han probado ser efectivas.